# Not able to access fn variable after while True condition

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

Im trying run code at every 2 min interval and  trying to access df cell value at specific time interval through while loop. But not able access the same even after declaring df as global in fn. How to get value df['col'].iloc[-1] after while condition. Help in this regard appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep     
import time, pause
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending
sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone='Asia/Kolkata')
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-sat', hour=16, minute=12,second=0)
def scheduled_job():
    print('job started....',datetime.now().time())
    @repeat(schedule.every(2).minutes.at(":00"))
    
    def ttm():
        print('function check....')
   
    def dta_frame():
        global df
        
        print("*** main loop ***", datetime.now().time())
        data = {'Name':['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],'Age':[27, 24, 22, 32],'Address':['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'],'Rank':[2, 4, 10, 1]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print (df)
    
    def addn():
        x = 25*25
        print(x, datetime.now().time())
    
    def multi():
        y= 10*50
        print(y, datetime.now().time())
    
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        ts = time.time()
        tgt= (datetime.fromtimestamp(ts + 118 - ts % 120))
        d_time =(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts))
    
        while d_time > tgt:
            if df['Rank'].iloc[-1]==1:
                addn()
                time.sleep(1)
                pause.until(tgt)
                break
      
            elif df['Rank'].iloc[-1]==0:              
                multi()
                time.sleep(1)
                pause.until(tgt)
                break
          
            else:
                print("No loop executed",datetime.now().time())
                time.sleep(1)
                pause.until(tgt)
                break
sched.start()
```

Comment: You have to define `df` at a higher level before you can refer to it as `global`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `df` outside `dta_frame()`, declare it outside `dta_frame()` or return it from the subroutine.

Comment: Grammar How it can be declared as I'm newbie to python can pl elaborate little. I'm getting this error:

Comment: Job "scheduled_job (trigger: cron[day_of_week='mon-sat', hour='16', minute='12', second='0'], next run at: 2022-06-20 16:12:00 IST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
 
    if df['Rank'].iloc[-1]==1:
NameError: name 'df' is not defined